# Javascript - Put an html element above canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to add through jquery or javascript an input field in a custom position above the `<canvas>` element?

I have tried the following:

- changing the z-index of the `canvas`- and `input`-field
- putting the canvas in an `div` with `relative` property and the `input`-field inside a `div` with `absolute` position, but then there are those ugly scrollbar, which I do not really want there.

My `index.html` page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">

<head>
    <title>WebApp</title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/jquery.ajaxmanager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/jquery.model.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.16/webfont.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; visibility: visible;">
            JavaScript ist in Ihrem Browser deaktiviert. Bitte aktivieren Sie es um diese Applikation zu starten.
            <p>
                JavaScript é disattivato nel Suo browser. Si prega di attivarlo per usare questa applicazione.
                <p>
                    JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Please enable it to use this application.
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://www.activatejavascript.org/">How to?</a>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <canvas id="app" width="150" height="30"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Through javascript I am adding other canvas:

```
//This is the main canvas
this.canvas.style.zIndex = 6;
this.canvas.style.position = "absolute";
this.canvas.style.border = "0px solid";
this.canvas.style.top = 0 + "px";
this.canvas.style.left = 0 + "px";

//Some other canvas elements
var show_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$(this.canvas).parent().append(show_canvas);
show_canvas.style.zIndex = 4;

var other_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$(this.canvas).parent().append(show_canvas);
other_canvas.style.zIndex = 0;

var another_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$(this.canvas).parent().append(show_canvas);
another_canvas.style.zIndex = 3;
another_canvas.attr('id', 'another_canvas');

var container = document.createElement('div');
$(container).attr('id', 'input_container');
$('#another_canvas').append(container);

var user = document.createElement('input');
var pass = document.createElement('input');

$(user).attr('id', 'username');
$(pass).attr('id', 'password');

$(container).append(user);
$(container).append(pass);

$('#input_container').css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'z-index': '100'
});
```

Currently it is looking like this: [image: Screenshot of the current status]

It would be awesome, if some of you could help me solve my problem XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the canvas and the input in a div with the div having "position: relative;" and the children having "position: absolute;" is the solution. If you want no scrollbars then either make sure the stuff inside the div is smaller than the div OR set "overflow: hidden".

One thing extra, set the canvas display type to "block". Without that the canvas is type "span" which adds space and causes a scrollbar to appear if the canvas is set to be 100%

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('#c1').getContext('2d');
const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
ctx.fillStyle = "#0FF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, Math.min(width, height) / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#form {
 position: absolute;
 left: 1em;
 top: 1em;
 padding: 0.5em;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#form input {
  font-size: 20pt;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
  <div id="form">
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

you had your canvas 150x30? That's pretty small but we can adjust the sizes

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('#c1').getContext('2d');
const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
ctx.fillStyle = "#0FF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, Math.min(width, height) / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#form {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#form input {
  font-size: 8px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
  <div id="form">
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks for your help. But one more question. How am I able to position the inputs?

Comment: where do you want them to be? I assume you wanted them to move as a group which is why they are surrounded by `<div id="form">`. So you can set `#form { left: 10px; top: 15px }` or whatever to position. If the inputs go outside the div though you'll get a scrollbar unless you add `overflow:hidden` to the container. But if the inputs go outside the container than part of them would be hidden and so unusable by the user.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day XD